# Set up a Jquery table to enable disqus comments to be retrieved and displayable on a html table

Tags: php, mysql

This is a not programming question, I request if is possible to do and if you have any preliminary indications to suggest

I find this
http://www.bluefinengineering.com/blog/custom-php-disqus-comments-data-sync-se

I use [datatables](https://datatables.net/) (PHP table) to find and filter many records in simply row display.
In the future I wish to filter also disqus users comments stored on my blog site, filtering user comments to find a specific content but displayed on my datatable table according to a criterion based on some keywords

1. Is possible to store and import disqus comments posted on my blog to import disqus user comments on mysql ?
2. After imported and store comments locally (in your database) how you could set up comments to enable them to be filtered with your personal search engine ?In my example I have set up a Jquery table to allow to find in this way

*column1, column2, column3*

```
|1 user |2| comment content |3| post where the comment has been inserted
```

If I type "spielberg" I expect to retrieve all 'spielberg' words to have something like this

Datatables have columns set up in this way

> *user* || *comment content* || 
>       topic where comment content has been inserted

```
user1 || ...spielberg it was... || the post ||
user1 || .. spielberg.. || E.T ||
user2 || .. spielberg.. || E.T ||
user43 || .. spielberg.. || E.T ||
```

Do you think it's possible or the job is too laborious ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! A programming question doesn't necessarily need to ask "can this code do X" or "how do you do Y in language Z". You are asking about how to interact with databases, which sounds like a programming/development question to me; unless I've missed the point?

Comment: thanks bertieb, is not exact, I'm asking if, according to you, this job could be laborious or maybe it's easy, I read how I can interact with database, I need just an opinion about my question XD